# $.get как заставить работать

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Имеется:

```
<a class=link href=purchases_inv_detail.asp?id_i=цифры&from=account>link2</a>
<a class=link href=purchases_inv_detail.asp?id_i=цифры&from=account>link1</a>
```

хочу спарсить цифры из аттрибута, и отправить их .get'ом, получая результат, но что-то не выходит, пишу вот так:

```
$('a').each(function(){
var url = /\d+(?!id_i)/.exec($(this).attr('href'))
$.get('ajax.asp', {action: 'debates', id_i: url, dataType: 'json', async: false}).success(function(e){ if(/текст/.test((e.html).toString())) alert('all good')})
});
```

Если убрать .each и попробовать руками отправить .get зарос, подставляя руками один из айдишников, то все работает норм, но если ставить на поток, то есть добавлять .each и парсить цифры автоматом через переменную url, то он просто к консоле выводит список ссылок с их аттрибутами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш пример работает, get-запрос уходит со всеми параметрами. Единственное, на что можно обратить внимание - это то, что если вы хотите отправлять значением свойства `id_i` число, то присваивать нужно не `url`, а `url[0]`, т. к. результатом выполнения `exec()` является массив (либо `null`). Ну и точки с запятой терять не стоит, разумеется

```
$('a').each(function(){
    var url = /\d+(?!id_i)/.exec($(this).attr('href'));
    console.log(url[0]);
    $.get('ajax.asp', {
        action: 'debates',
        id_i: url[0],
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false
    });
});
```

Обновление: если необходимо отправлять данные **при нажатии на ссылку**, то код должен выглядеть иначе:

```
$('a').click(function(){
        var url = /\d+(?!id_i)/.exec($(this).attr('href'));
        console.log(url[0]);
        $.get('ajax.asp', {
            action: 'debates',
            id_i: url[0],
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false
        });
    });
```

Comment: если в массиве _один_ элемент, то нет разницы, передавать его `url` или `url[0]`

Comment: а если необходимо передать абсолютно все значения...но через цикл не хочется, разве .each не решает проблему ? может .map и тд (map'ом ни разу не пользовался, сорри за чепуху)

Comment: @Grundy, почему нет разницы? Разница как минимум в типе данных на отправляющей и принимающей стороне: `typeof(url) == 'object'`, а `typeof(url[0]) == 'string'`. При этом `gettype($_GET['id_i'])== 'object'` для первого случая и `gettype($_GET['id_i'])== 'string'` для второго

Comment: @silverxak вопрос не совсем понятен. вы хотите передать все значения одним запросом? `each()` это по сути и есть цикл

Comment: @alenkins, да, это я не посмотрел, что jQuery не просто к строке значение приводит. Если бы вызывалось просто `toString`, то `['value'] == 'value'`

Comment: @alenkins, сами понимаете ссылка - это определенная кнопка, по нажатию на нее происходит определенное действие, и вот я пишу расширение, со многими функциями, и хочу чтобы он по определенной проверке отправлял запрос который происходит при нажатии на кнопку...с проверкой то все норм, а вот с отправкой проблемы

Comment: @silverxak, в таком случае вам нужно использовать не `each()`, а обработку события, в данном случае `click()`. Обновила ответ

Comment: @alenkins, при нажатии на кнопку мышкой, отправляется запрос, если отправить этот же запрос без нажатия мышкой о кнопке, вы думаете результат будет другой ?

Comment: @silverxak, сформулируйте задачу так, чтобы она была понятна не только вам

Comment: @alenkins есть список ссылок, с уникальными айди, которые при нажатии на ссылку(кнопку) отправляют запрос в теле которого передают этот айди, хочу, чтобы при открытии страницы, все эти запросы отправлялись без нажатия на кнопку..

Comment: Если именно запросЫ, то первое решение должно полностью решить вашу задачу (если нет - опишите получаемую при выполнении скрипта ошибку). Если вы хотите одним запросом отправить все id из ссылок в массиве, то это можно сделать так https://jsfiddle.net/amd535o3/

Comment: @alenkins решилось все проще, не ожидал что так вообще работатет js...я в параметр при передаче запросе не url поставил, а url[0], даже без инкремента...очень странно..не понял почему...